# jQuery function does not change global variable while regular javascript functions do

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a reason that this code:

```
var verb = "";

    function printPage (input) {
            $("div").append(input + "<br>");
    }

    $( "#submit" ).click(function() {
       verb = $('#enter').val();
       printPage(verb);
    });

    printPage(verb);
```

only results in #enter (a form)'s value being logged once in the click event (while the last printPage prints the original empty string), while this code:

```
var verb = "";

function printPage (input) {
        $("div").append(input + "<br>");
}

function buttonClick() {
  verb = "verb!";
  printPage(verb);
}

buttonClick();
printPage(verb);
```

prints verb twice, as the function has successfully changed the verb variable value? Sorry if I haven't explained my problem well enough, I'll elaborate more if needed.

Comment: try without var ... like verb = ""; if you have to make anything global then dont use var with it.

Comment: The function passed to `$( "#submit" ).click(...)` will be triggered *only* when you click the button. Whereas in the second case, since you are explicitly calling `buttonClick()`, it'll log twice.

Comment: #enter is a input or html tag?

Comment: @Rahul - Not true. You can use `var x` in global scope to make something global (though var is not strictly needed). More importantly in this case, it need not be global, it can be limited to the parent scope, which I believe should be the function bound to `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @techfoobar Yes, it is in the function bound to $(document).ready(). Is there any way to pass the verb value from #enter to the global variable verb when it is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `buttonClick` function runs before the `printPage` function -- and that makes the `verb` variable hold 'verb!'. The `printPage` function is run twice AFTER the `verb` var has the 'verb!' value in it.

In the case of the jQuery, `printPage` function is run right away while `verb` is empty. ONLY when you CLICK the button, then `verb` has a value.

Comment: I see what you mean. So if I were somehow able to run console.log(verb); after the button was clicked, it would correctly log the form value to console?

Comment: Yes -- that's right. verb is empty until the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

input value may be empty so you might be seeing unchanged, you may use like this:

```
verb = $('#enter').val() || 'verb';
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery or not, it would change the variable if your method was run and if the value of $('#enter') isn't blank ( otherwise, you wouldn't see a change ).

To test this out, put `console.log( verb );` before and after the `verb = $('#enter').val();`.  You will either see that your onClick method isn't being called, or even that it doesn't have a value.

```
var verb = "";

function printPage (input) {
        $("div").append(input + "<br>");
}

$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
   console.log( verb );
   verb = $('#enter').val();
   console.log( verb );
   printPage(verb);
   console.log( verb );
});

printPage(verb);
```

My guess is that you're not using the correct selector ( instead of #enter,  you should be using a different id/class selector ) or that the value is actually empty.

Edit: In case you are wondering what console.log is doing, its writing it to your browser's console ( apologies if you already know this ).  Should be abel to open this up and see the debug logs that we're printing.

You could also just alert( verb ) if you wanted to do that instead.

Comment: I was approaching the problem the wrong way! The problem was that the verb value was empty due to the button not being pressed. Thanks for your input though!